# Reading data files in blogdown

Tags: r, csv, blogdown

I am a new user of blogdown using Hugo.  I would like to create a new post that includes R code to read a data file.

The data file is in my static folder, local path `C:\mydir\myblogdown\static\data\savedrecs.txt`.  Since I was successful in referring to an image using a relative path like this, `![](/images\myimage.jpg)`, I tried reading the data using something similar for the data file, `read.csv("/data\savedrecs.txt")`, but that didn't work.

I started playing around with the `list.files()` function to see if I could find a relative path that worked in my local version of the post, `list.files("../../static/data")` worked, showing me `## [1] "savedrecs.txt"`.

I tried searching around other folks' blogdown repos on Github to see how they might have referred to a data file, but the only example I found referred to a data file using a URL.

Comment: I've managed to add a data (CSV) file to a blogdown post, by putting it in the same directory as the Rmd file and reading it via a Rmd chunk. Perhaps it is the location of your text file?

Comment: You can certainly `read.csv("../../static/data/savedrecs.txt")` in Rmd.

Comment: Yes, @Yihui.  I was avoiding doing that because I thought I wasn't supposed to refer specifically to "static" in the blogdown / Hugo world ... I thought things in "static" were supposed to end up in "public" ... or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that this may be due to the location of your data file. In my working example, the Rmd form of my blog post is in the directory, called `p0bs/content/post`. I also add my data file (a CSV in my case) to this directory.

I then treat the rest of the post as I would in a standard Rmarkdown website, with Rmd chunks (that are named without spaces). In your case, that code would include:

`read.csv("savedrecs.txt")`

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Pleased to hear it